# Can not open file in Quickfix when Using CtrlP

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

When I pressed enter in the vimgrep quickfix window on a filename entry , the ctrlp search result window would pop up automatically even if I didn't call it and the file would not be opened. vim-Ack and Ag had the same situation. But when I disabled CtrlP plugin, vimgrep, vim-Ack and Ag worked properly. And I didn't find any option in CtrlP that can configure this behavior. How Can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Use CtrlP's issue tracker, of course.

Comment: I use CtrlP and I don't have that problem.

Comment: Basically, CtrlP doesn't set any key mappings for the qf window.
Can you put the result of `:verb map <cr>` in the Quickfix window please

Answer (score 0):

You might have CtrlP mapped to `<C-m>`. But `<C-m>` is a terminal shortkey for `<CR>` symbol. So, hitting `<C-m>` is the same as hitting `<CR>`